# Consumindo uma API com Angular

Tags: api, http, typescript, angular

Estou tentando consumir uma API com Angular 5 mas ele me retorna esse erro:

```
" Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
    at DefaultIterableDiffer.diff".
```

Resposta da API :

```
    {
    "alunos": [
        {
            "aluno": {
                "id": 655,
                "nome": "Gustavo Henrique",
                "status": "Ativo"
            },
            "mensalidade": {
                "status": "Pago"
            }
        },
        {
            "aluno": {
                "id": 656,
                "nome": "Vivien Jacobs",
                "status": "Ativo"
            },
            "mensalidade": {
                "status": "Débito"
            }
        }
     ]
}
```

Meu serviço:

```
import { IStudent } from './../students';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http/src/response';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';


@Injectable()
export class StudentsService {

  public alunos = [];

  // LIST STUDENTS URL
  public list_students_url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/aluno/list';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


  // Pega todos os alunos.
  getAlunos(): Observable<IStudent[]>
  {
      return this.http.get<IStudent[]>(this.list_students_url)
                      .catch(this.errorHandler);
  }




  errorHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse)
  {
      return Observable.throw(error.message || "Server error");
  }

}
```

Minha interface:

```
export interface IStudent {
alunos: {
    aluno: {
        id: number,
        nome: string,
        status: string,
    },
    mensalidade: {
        status: string
    }
  }
}
```

Meu component:

```
import { StudentsService } from './services/students.service';
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { IStudent } from './students';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-students',
  templateUrl: './students.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./students.component.css']
})
export class StudentsComponent implements OnInit {

  public students = [];
  public errorMsg;
  constructor(private service: StudentsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

      this.service.getAlunos()
      .subscribe( data => this.students = data,
                 error => this.errorMsg = error);


                 //console.log(this.students);
  }

}
```

Comment: A ***comunidade*** da a opção de colocar códigos no corpo da pergunta, se poder fazer o **favor** de [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/272251/edit) e colocar, basta colar o código, selecionar e aperta o atalho **CTRL+K** que ira formatar o mesmo..

Comment: Entendi, corrigido =)

Comment: Sua interface está incorreta, você não está declarando o array que está no corpo do JSON

Answer (score 0):

O problema e que vc nao esta recebendo um array e sim um  objeto que contem um array.

```
export interface GetAlunosResponse {
     alunos: Estudante[];
}

export interface Estudante: {
      aluno:Aluno;
      mensalidade:Mensalidade;
}

export interface Aluno: {
     id: number,
     nome: string,
     status: string,
}  

export interface Mensalidade: {
     status: string
}
```

No service:

```
 getAlunos(): Observable<GetAlunosResponse[]>
  {
      return this.http.get<GetAlunosResponse[]>(this.list_students_url)
                      .catch(this.errorHandler);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Faça a seguinte alteração no método **getAlunos()**

```
 getAlunos(): Observable<IStudent[]> {
   return this.http.get<IStudent[]>(this.list_students_url).pipe(
   tap(data => JSON.stringify(data))),
   catchError(this.errorHandler)
 );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Sua estrutura esta errada em um geral. Primeiramente para mapear os objetos retornados do Json é necessário criar uma classe, e não uma interface. Não entendi muito bem o que você pretende fazer, mas no caso como exemplo, você teria que criar uma classe Aluno:

```
export class Aluno {
    id: number;
    nome: string;
    status: string;
    mensalidade: string;
}
```

Resposta correta da API:

```
{
    "id": 655,
    "nome": "Gustavo Henrique",
    "status": "Ativo",
    "mensalidade": "Pago"
},
{
    "id": 656,
    "nome": "Vivien Jacobs",
    "status": "Ativo"
    "mensalidade": "Débito"
}
```

Seu método getAlunos

```
getAlunos(): Observable<Aluno[]>
  {
    return this.http.get(this.list_students_url).pipe(
          map((res: Response) => {
              return res.json();
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError),);
  }
```

Comment: Interfaces sao mais recomendados que classes para mapear apis pois geram menos codigo.